# Java JPA setParameter date object

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have this function in my PostgreSQL database.

```
create or replace function borrowaCar(integer,integer,date) returns boolean language 'plpgsql' as'
declare 
    borrow boolean;
begin
     if exists(select * from availableCars where id=$2)then
            insert into Borrows (car_id_car, person_id_person, borrow_date, return_date) values ($2,$1,$3, NULL);
            update Car set is_borrow=true where id_car=$2;
            return true;
     end if;
    return false;
end;
';
```

When I build query I would like to add actual date in YYYY-MM-DD like 2017-09-06. I write this code:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT borrowaCar(?,?,?)");          
query.setParameter(1, idPerson);
query.setParameter(2, idCar);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
query.setParameter(3, sdf.format(date));
```

But this solution returns error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function borrowacar(integer,
>   integer, character varying) does not exist   Wskazówka: No function
>   matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
>   explicit type casts.

Whats the problem?

Comment: sdf.format  returns a String

Comment: Yes, I guess. How to correct this?

Comment: If the type of borrow_date is date then do not use sdf.format and take date directly. If the type is charvar then change the function signature from int,int,date to int,int,String

Comment: Ok, but field in my table is date type.

Comment: so try query.setParameter(3, date);

Comment: When I put date to filed I have date and time, but I want to store only year, month, day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that your defined function

```
borrowaCar(integer, integer, date)
```

does not match your Parameters:

```
borrowacar(integer, integer, character varying)
```

The call of sdf.format(date) returns a String and is interpreted as "character varying". You need to take the type definded in Column borrow_date of Table Borrows.

Comment: Yes, I known sdf.format(date) return  String. I want to put object to my function not String with character varing.

Comment: you could try to cast:  .....values ($2,$1,CAST($3 AS DATETIME), NULL);  or something like that. You need then to change borrowaCar(integer, integer, date)  to borrowacar(integer, integer, character varying).   Maybe there is a autocast if you just change the method signature without casting

Comment: Ok thanks, I try that. There is no possible to return date object with only year, month, day?